# Try-Catch inside a while loop in Java

Tags: java, file-io, while-loop, try-catch

So basically my code is trying to read off a .txt file and then create objects with those variables (long,string,string,double,double). When a variable in the .txt file ISN'T a long or string or double, it's written into another file. I've written the code of this but it doesn't go past the first `catch (InputMismatchException n)`. What is wrong with my code?

```
int i = 0;
ArrayList<Employee> ArrEmployee = new ArrayList<Employee>(); //  array for employee objects

try {
    Scanner txtIn = new Scanner(new File("payroll.txt"));


    while (txtIn.hasNext()) { // looping through the payroll.txt file and creating Employee objects from its data
        try {
            long EmployeeNumber = txtIn.nextLong();
            String EmployeeName = txtIn.next();
            String LastName = txtIn.next();
            double HoursWorked = txtIn.nextDouble();
            double HourlyWage = txtIn.nextDouble();
            if (HourlyWage > 10.35){ 
                throw new InputMismatchException(); // throws exception if the hourly wage is less than 10.35$
            }
            else
                ArrEmployee.add(new Employee(EmployeeNumber,EmployeeName,LastName,HoursWorked,HourlyWage)); // creates Employee objects according to the input payroll.txt
            i++;
        } catch (InputMismatchException n) { // catching long,strings and doubles in the payroll.txt that aren't valid
            PrintWriter txtOut = new PrintWriter("payrollError.txt");
            txtOut.println(Employee.EmployeeNumber + " " + Employee.EmployeeName + " " + Employee.LastName + " " + Employee.HoursWorked + " " + Employee.HourlyWage);
            txtOut.close();
        }
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File payroll.txt was not found.");
}
```

The path files are OK. I've shortened it for easier understanding.

Comment: When it doesn't go past catch block, it means you caught an exception.

Comment: @OP try writing your own exception or handle this differently.

Comment: There are two `try` and one `catch` - please post a complete working example (and if you'll bother to indent it - it would be great). Further, do you get any exception ? stacktrace ? did you add debug prints ?

Comment: Your problem is that your code is improperly formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor you're using for `PrintWriter` actually overwrites the file if it already exists. From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.lang.String)):

> `fileName` - The name of the file to use as the destination of this writer. **If the file exists then it will be truncated to zero size**; otherwise, a new file will be created. The output will be written to the file and is buffered.

You should create `txtOut` once before the loop and close it after the loop. This way it will only be opened once and not started from scratch for every exception caught.